# DataGridView refreshing fixed position in row filter textbox in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, gridview, datagridview, bindingsource

I want when filtering rows in the textbox then the database is updated from other applications then I do a refresh I want the datagridview that I filter in the textbox in a fixed position and also when selected in the combobox as well. Maybe my code isn't perfect. So there may be the best solution.

Thanks
[VIEW DATAGRIDVIEW](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kg831.png)

```
Public Class Form1
    Dim Path As String = Application.StartupPath()
    Dim cn = "provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0; data source=" & Path & "; Extended Properties=dBase IV"
    Private WithEvents dt As New DataTable
    Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Me.PopulateComboBox()
        Me.PopulateDataGridView()
        Me.clearfiltercombobox()
    End Sub
    Private Sub PopulateDataGridView()
        Try
            Dim query = "select ITM,ART,QTY FROM EXAMPLE WHERE QTY > 0 AND BRAND = @BRAND"
            Using con As OleDbConnection = New OleDbConnection(cn)
                Using cmd As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand(query, con)
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@BRAND", ComboBox1.SelectedValue)
                    Using adapter As New OleDbDataAdapter(cmd)
                        Dim dt As DataTable = New DataTable()
                        adapter.Fill(dt)
                        Me.DataGridView1.DataSource = dt
                    End Using
                End Using
            End Using
        Catch myerror As OleDbException
            MessageBox.Show("Error: " & myerror.Message)
        Finally
        End Try
    End Sub
    Private Sub TextBox1_TextChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles TextBox1.TextChanged
        Try
            CType(DataGridView1.DataSource, DataTable).DefaultView.RowFilter = String.Format("ITM LIKE '%{0}%' OR ITM LIKE '%{0}%'", TextBox1.Text)
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox("No match found")
        End Try
    End Sub
    Private Sub ComboBox1_SelectionChangeCommitted(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles ComboBox1.SelectionChangeCommitted
        Me.TextBox1.Text = ""
        Me.PopulateDataGridView()
    End Sub
    Private Sub PopulateComboBox()
        Dim query As String = "SELECT DISTINCT BRAND FROM EXAMPLE WHERE QTY > 0"
        Try
            Using con As OleDbConnection = New OleDbConnection(cn)
                Using sda As OleDbDataAdapter = New OleDbDataAdapter(query, con)
                    'Fill the DataTable with records from Table.
                    Dim dt As DataTable = New DataTable()
                    sda.Fill(dt)
                    'Insert the Default Item to DataTable.
                    Dim row As DataRow = dt.NewRow()
                    row(0) = ""
                    dt.Rows.InsertAt(row, 0)
                    'Assign DataTable as DataSource.
                    ComboBox1.DataSource = dt
                    ComboBox1.DisplayMember = "BRAND"
                    ComboBox1.ValueMember = "BRAND"
                End Using
            End Using
        Catch myerror As OleDbException
            MessageBox.Show("Error: " & myerror.Message)
        Finally
        End Try
    End Sub
    Private Sub clearfiltercombobox()
        Try
            ComboBox1.ResetText()
            TextBox1.Text = ""
            Dim query = "select ITM,ART,QTY FROM EXAMPLE WHERE QTY > 0"
            Using con As OleDbConnection = New OleDbConnection(cn)
                Using cmd As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand(query, con)
                    Using adapter As New OleDbDataAdapter(cmd)
                        Dim dt As DataTable = New DataTable()
                        adapter.Fill(dt)
                        Me.DataGridView1.DataSource = dt
                    End Using
                End Using
            End Using
        Catch myerror As OleDbException
            MessageBox.Show("Error: " & myerror.Message)
        Finally
        End Try
    End Sub
    Private Sub Refreshonly_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Refreshonly.Click
        Me.clearfiltercombobox()
        DataGridView1.Refresh()
    End Sub
    Private Sub clearall_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Clearall.Click
        Me.clearfiltercombobox()
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Struggling to understand your question, Is it you simply want to preserve the currently selected record and filter settings and re-apply them after you call PopulateDataGridView()?

Comment: @Hursey , yes, that's right I want to preserve the currently selected record and filter settings and re-apply them after I call PopulateDataGridView(). Is there a best solution?